# How do I get Tkinter treeview checkbox to set on/off value and variable, etc like I did with Tkinter checkbutton?

Tags: tkinter, treeview, robotframework, tk-toolkit

I am just a software tester with autism and other learning disabilities that is struggling to learn python. I know robot framework very well. I am learning python through trial and error and wrote my first script that is a Test Runner. It uses tkinter checkbuttons to run tests in groups. But I want to split the test up out of their groups so that I can run them individually, but not have a massive tkinter window full of 50 tests. I would like to use tkinter CheckboxTreeview or anything else you can recommend that collapses the test with checkboxes in a treeview. I undertsand how tkinter CheckBoxTreeview basically works, but how do i attach each test to each checkbox in the treeview so that it runs when the box is checked and I click run? Below is an example of my current code. I have not added the treeview, because I don't get how to use it for what I'm trying to do. Thank you.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
import threading as Thread
import robot
from robot import run_cli
from robot import rebot_cli


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
info_label = Label(text="Check tests to run")

def threading1():
    th1=threading.Thread(target=option)
    th1.start()

frame1 = LabelFrame(root, width=400, height=400)
frame1.pack()

frame2 = LabelFrame(root, width=400, height=400) 
frame2.pack()


var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()
var3 = IntVar()

c1 = Checkbutton(frame1, text = "Test1", onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable = var1)
c1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W, columnspan = 6)
c2 = Checkbutton(frame1, text = "Test2", onvalue=2, offvalue=0, variable = var2)
c2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W, columnspan = 6)
c3 = Checkbutton(frame1, text = "Test3", onvalue=3, offvalue=0, variable = var3)
c3.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W, columnspan = 6)

def option():
    if var1.get() ==1:
        rc = robot.run_cli(['-t', 'Test1'])
    if var2.get() ==2:
        rc = robot.run_cli(['-t', 'Test2'])
    if var3.get() ==3:
        rc = robot.run_cli(['-t', 'Test3'])

def stop_all():
    os.system("killall -9 chromedriver")
    os.system("killall -9 chrome")
    pidx = os.getpid()
    cmd1 = "kill" + "" + str(pidx)
    if __name__== "__main__":
        os.system(cmd1)

start = Button(frame2, text="Start", width=10, height=3, bg='green', command=threading1)
stop = Button(frame2, text="Quit", width=10, height=3, bg='red', command=stop_all)

root.mainloop()
```

This is how i want it to look:
[TestRunner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORYAj.png)

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code. As posted it has countless syntax errors.

Comment: sorry about that. first post.

Comment: Not wanting to diverge you from learning Python, but RIDE (https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE) contains trees with test selection. You may learn from RIDE's code, which is done using wxPython.org, but better is to see their demo. Also, maybe you can benefit to join our Slack. Good luck.

Comment: @Helio, I use RIDE for editing, but I want something a little more minimalistic for running tests.